# I am confused in sql like query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get numbers in b/w `[word]__.png` like

```
word1.png , word2.png word3......word10.png
```

but get in a sequence like 1,2,3,..... I'm trying on this query but it doesn't return the data in sequence starting from 1 :

```
select * from psl_table where  values like 'word_%.png'
```

Comment: `where columnname like 'str1%' or columnname like 'str2%' ...`, but you probably want regexp_like or similar.

Comment: which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Is it like a string or in columns?

Comment: Do you mean you want the ordering of rows to be based on the number part?

Comment: simply order by `values` will give you the desired result

Comment: but it show the sequence like this
word1.png
word10.png
word11.png
......
word19.png
word2.png
word21.png
.....
word29.png

Comment: @lali no it won't. It will order lexographically, so "11" is less than "2"

Comment: I'm using this query in a C# application

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: yes @Bohemian I want to get the numbers in proper order

Comment: my dbms is sql server but my output is there in a c# application

Comment: Your filename convention is the issue. Try using a fixed number of digits, so your images are named like word0001.png word0002.png and so on. With this, the alphanumerical ordering works as well

Comment: This is because the datatype of your column is varchar. Try converting it and then go for order by. Try adding this in your query:  
          `ORDER BY CAST(pic_number AS SIGNED)`

Comment: I can't convert it into other data type because it is the address of pictures..
could you please evaluate order by cast(pic_number as signed) @ki

Answer (score 1):

Extract the number part, cast to INT, and sort on that:

```
select * from psl_table
where values like 'word_%.png'
order by cast(substring(values, 6, length(values) - 10) as int)
```

Comment: substr is not considered as built in function,

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Replace functionality in SQL Server. First of you search your string then replace "word" & ".png" from your values then convert it to "INT" and order it. I've tested it, check below SQL:

```
Create Table psl_table
(
    [values] NVarChar(MAX)
)

Insert Into psl_table Values('word1.png')
Insert Into psl_table Values('word2.png')
Insert Into psl_table Values('word3.png')
Insert Into psl_table Values('word4.png')
Insert Into psl_table Values('word001.png')
Insert Into psl_table Values('word12.png')
Insert Into psl_table Values('word6.png')
Insert Into psl_table Values('word8.png')
Insert Into psl_table Values('word10.png')
Insert Into psl_table Values('word9.png')

select * from psl_table where [values] like 'word%.png' order by Convert(Int,Replace(Replace([values],'.png',''),'word',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

**This has to work!!!**

```
  SELECT Convert(INT,(SUBSTRING(values, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', values), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', values + 'g') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',values) + 1))) AS Number FROM psl_table Order by Number
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for the earlier answer, that was not fitting the situation

```
DECLARE @TABLE AS TABLE(ITEM nvarchar(200))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES('myimage11.png')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES('myimage2.png')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES('myimage6.png')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES('myimage3.png')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES('myimage1.png')
```

converting into integer for the purpose of sorting (using common table expression - CTE)

```
;WITH CTE AS (
select CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(ITEM, 8, CHARINDEX('.', ITEM, 0) - 8)) INTVAL FROM @TABLE
)
SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY INTVAL
```

Here is the result, remember the actual order in above insert queries

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect and doesn't help the OP at all because it will order "word_11.png" *before* "word_2.png"

Comment: This won't work, because it would sort "word10.png" instantly after "word1.png" instead of numerical ordering